# open text file with 'Sublime text3' in terminal

Tags: terminal, sublimetext3

I could open the file with Textmate using `mate`.

```
mate file.txt
```

I'd love to do the same thing with sublimetext3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /bin/subl
```

And launch sublime as subl

Comment: Or put it in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin instead of using the /bin. I prefer to keep my /bin with os tools.